# O IP influencia no ranqueamento do site?

Tags: seo

Gostaria de saber se o IP influencia no ranqueamento no Google.

Recentemente migrei um site da Azure(IP exclusivo) para uma hospedagem compartilhada(IP compartilhado) e o site caiu de posição(página 1,2 e as vezes 3 para página 14).

Talvez a resposta esteja na própria experiência observada, porém gostaria de saber tecnicamente se o IP influência no ranqueamento.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse material, pode ajudar: https://www.wapstore.com.br/blog/como-a-hospedagem-do-site-influencia-o-seo-2/

Comment: O `ip` eu não sei se influencia, mas o domínio continuou o mesmo?

Comment: Estou perguntando isso porque tinha uns domínios que o Google por padrão dava menos ranqueamento um tempo atrás  (acho que era a época do `co.cc` e o `.tk`), que geralmente eram usados para spam e afins.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters mesmo domínio...

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti será que nessa troca aí o Google não conseguiu pegar alguma informação? ou algo começou a dar erros? Que eu me lembro, muitos erros 404 podem afetar o ranqueamento (preciso confirmar, pois tem tantas teorias em cima de o que o Google ranqueia ou não). **E o mais importante: Você usa o WebMaster do Google?**

Comment: Sim uso sim, eu só troquei de hospedagem, o site em sí é o mesmo... regras de negócio e etc, foi um CTRL C V

Comment: As vezes pode estar relacionado ao redirect, pq provavelmente vc tb apontou o DNS para outro host. Olha se isso pode te dar uma luz. https://marketingdeconteudo.com/redirect-302/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Servidor compartilhado piora sim o seu ranking, por experiencias como você mesmo observou como também já ocorreram com Devs. Ninguém sabe exatamente quais são s regras do PageRank, porem foram observados que algumas questões influenciam. Você pode ler mais aki [fatores-de-rankeamento-do-google](https://marketingdeconteudo.com/fatores-de-rankeamento-do-google/), essa matéria me ajudou a entender melhor o SEO.

O que pode ocorrer também é a questão de spam e backlinks, já que o bots do google só te localizam pelo o IP do seu servidor, quando você é penalizado por fazer BlackHat ele penaliza o IP então se outro site faz ou está sendo penalizado você acaba sendo penalizado também.Tanto que uma das praticas para fazer um backlink próprio é ter outros sites que façam o Rel=Follow para o site e que estejam em outros servidores.

Comment: "span" ou "spam"?

Answer (score 1):

Influenciar, sempre influencia, inclusive se você migrar seu DNS.

Sempre que me deparei com essa situação, aceitei a regra que tinha que refazer um trabalho de re-indexação e, com o tempo, chegava novamente ao resultado desejado.

Na maioria dos casos, tinha instâncias servidoras com baixa latência e ao mudar para um servidor compartilhado com maior latência automaticamente já influenciava nas análises feitas por ferramentas como o GTMetrix, WebPageTest e Semalt. O WebPageTest tem um indicador ótimo que é o tempo inicial de resposta.

É recomendado realizar uma revisão dos gargalos do site, se possível, ativando o cacheamento, expires (htaacess), compactação (gzip) e mimificação de recursos.

No caso do ranqueamento do site nos mecanismos de busca da Google, Bing, Yandex e Baidu, recomendo acessar os ambientes webmasters de cada plataforma e forçar uma reindexação de todo o seu conteúdo e sitemaps.